# Functions hooking only hooks recv() and not send() using detour

Tags: c, winapi

i'm playing with some detours and function hooking and i'm having a strange issue with the following code:

Basically what happens is that both the DetourTransactionCommit() are successful, but only the recv() function is actually hooked, while the send isn't, as the

OutputDebugStringA("Sent packet!");

never triggers

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "WinInet.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "detours.h"
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "WinInet.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int (WINAPI *pSend)(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags) = send;
int WINAPI MySend(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags);

int (WINAPI *pRecv)(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags) = recv;
int WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags);


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    LONG errore;

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:

        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)pSend, MySend);
        if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR) {
            OutputDebugStringA("Send function hooked successfully");
        }
        else{
            OutputDebugStringA("Failed to hook Send function");
        }

        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)pRecv, MyRecv);
        if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR) {
            OutputDebugStringA("Recv function hooked successfully");
        }
        else{
            OutputDebugStringA("Failed to hook Recv function");
        }

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI MySend(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags) {
    OutputDebugStringA("Sent packet!");
    return pSend(s, buf, len, flags);
}

int WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags) {
    OutputDebugStringA("Received packet!");
    return pRecv(s, buf, len, flags);
}
```

UPDATE:
Appearently the problem with the function is related to the process i was trying to inject the DLL into.
It looks like trying to hook send() in internet explorer 11 x86 fails for reasons i still have to figure out.
I tried injecting the exact same DLL into another program using winsock2 (putty) and the function was hooked correctly.

Maybe anyone knows the reason for that to happen?

Comment: Maybe the hook never runs because `send()` is never called?  There's also `WSASend`, `WSASendMsg`, ... many different ways to write to a socket.

Comment: Don't the `WSASend*` functions call `send` under the hood anyway?

Comment: It'd be nice to see what your detour functionality does.

Comment: Ben was right, apparently send() is never called by internet explorer 11, i've tried hooking `WSASend()` and it hooked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As Ben Voigt pointed out, apparently send() is not called in internet explorer 11.
I've tried hooking `WSASend()` instead and it worked.

the edited working snipplet is the following:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "WinInet.h"
    #include "tchar.h"
    #include "windows.h"
    #include "detours.h"
    #include <Winsock2.h>
    #include <WS2tcpip.h>
    #include <crtdbg.h>

    #pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib, "WinInet.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int(WINAPI *pWSASend) (
    SOCKET s, 
    LPWSABUF lpBuffers, 
    DWORD dwBufferCount, 
    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesSent, 
    DWORD dwFlags, 
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, 
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine) = WSASend;

int WINAPI MyWSASend(
    SOCKET s,
    LPWSABUF lpBuffers,
    DWORD dwBufferCount,
    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesSent,
    DWORD dwFlags,
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped,
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine);


int (WINAPI *pRecv)(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags) = recv;
int WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags);


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    LONG errore;

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:

        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)pWSASend, MyWSASend);
        if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR) {
            OutputDebugStringA("Send function hooked successfully");
        }
        else{
            OutputDebugStringA("Failed to hook Send function");
        }

        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)pRecv, MyRecv);
        if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR) {
            OutputDebugStringA("Recv function hooked successfully");
        }
        else{
            OutputDebugStringA("Failed to hook Recv function");
        }

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI MyWSASend(
    SOCKET s,
    LPWSABUF lpBuffers,
    DWORD dwBufferCount,
    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesSent,
    DWORD dwFlags,
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped,
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine)
{
    OutputDebugStringA("Packet Sent!");
    return (pWSASend)(s, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesSent, dwFlags, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine);
};
int WINAPI MyRecv(SOCKET s, char* buf, int len, int flags) {
    OutputDebugStringA("Received packet!");
    return pRecv(s, buf, len, flags);
}
```